# How can I print only one row with specific id in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

This is my view:

```
@foreach($questions as $q)
    print question {{ $q->name }}
    @foreach($answer as $a)
        @if($a->question_id == $q->id)
            print answer {{ $a->name }} //here I want only one answer
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And this is my controller:

```
$questions = Question::get();
$answer = Answer::get();
return view('page', compact('questions', 'answer'));
```

I want to print questions, then only one answer per question. As there are many answers per question how can I limit it to print only one? Do I do it in controller somehow? I'm sorry I'm asking this a bit stupit question but I didn't know how to google it.

Comment: You need a relationship between questions and answers, for starters.

Comment: You could add a break after printing an answer when one is found.

Comment: @ceejayoz If you mean hasMany or belongsTo in model class then I have that.

Comment: @Denis Then you should be doing `$question->answers` to access the answers for the question via the relationship instead of `foreach`ing through ALL answers.

Comment: @KamilG. I solved it by adding a counter then breaking loop if counter equals to 1. But I don't think that is the right way to use Laravel.

Comment: @ceejayoz I think I need that, but how do I print a value with your method. Or if you can reference some docs about it I would be thankful.

Comment: `$questions->answers` will be a collection, which come with useful functions. Use `first()` to fetch the first one in the collection. Then reference its properties like any ther model. `$questions->answers->first()->name`

Comment: @ceejayoz Allright that did the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got relationships properly set up, it's as easy as this using Laravel's Collection class `first` method:

```
@foreach($questions as $q)
    print question {{ $q->name }}
    print answer {{ $q->answers->first()->name }}
@endforeach
```